# Show header of uitableview on scroll up and hide header of uitableview on scroll down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the following code to add programmatically in a UITableView a header

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 50, 276, 30)];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235/255.0f green:235/255.0f blue:235/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 5, 276, 24)];
labelView.text = @"hello";

[headerView addSubview:labelView];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

How do i show the header of the uitableview on scroll up and hide header of uitableview on scroll down. The UITableview is created also programmatically. Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.offsetY) {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
    } else {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
    }
    self.offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
```